# Emacs: font-lock-fontify-region and multiline

Tags: emacs, multiline, font-lock, font-lock-mode

I am writing a minor mode for php/html files. I use a function (cf. `font-lock-keywords`) to fontify `<?php` `?>` blocs.

In order to fontify multilined blocs, I need to set `font-lock-multiline` to t.

Everything is running quite nicely. Their is just a problem in this case :
When I have a multiline bloc and a delete the closing tag (`?>`) the bloc is unfontified. When I put the tag back, the block is not fontified again.

I have three questions :

1/ is there a simple solution to this problem

if not
2/ is there any way to trigger `font-lock-fontify-buffer` each time I type those two chars : 
'?''>'

3/ better, is there a way to trigger this kind a fonction : when I type `?>` I find the opening tag `<?php` and force a `font-lock-fontify-region` on this bloc.

Comment: Why are you writing custom fontifying functions? Isn't better to use [php-mode](http://php-mode.sourceforge.net/) or even better [some up-to-date fork](https://github.com/rradonic/php-mode) which has quite good fontifying for php files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic approach, and the logic is insufficient, but it demonstrates one option:

```
(defvar foo-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "foo-minor-mode keymap.")
(define-key foo-minor-mode-map (kbd ">") 'foo-electric-gt)

(defun foo-electric-gt (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*p")
  (when (looking-back "\\?$")
    (save-excursion
      (let ((end (- (point) 1))
            (beg (+ (search-backward "<?php") 5)))
        (font-lock-fontify-region beg end))))
  (insert-char ?> arg))

(define-minor-mode foo-minor-mode
  "foo mode.

\\{foo-minor-mode-map}"
  :keymap 'foo-minor-mode-map)
```

Comment: thx, I ve done almost the same thing with the hook : (add-hook 'after-change-functions 'psp-after-change t t)